# Press dot to record game in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

Sometimes when I start Hearthstone, it has a brief popup message that says "Press <*> to record your game" where <*> is just a large black dot.

What does this mean? I see no black dot in the Hearthstone interface.

Comment: Can't say for certain with Hearthstone but I've seen this plenty of times in other games when there isn't a specific key bound in settings. Meaning it's just showing a sorta blank key in it's place.

Comment: What platform do you play on? It might be something related to your GPU or OS on Windows, or a different app on your smartphone.

Answer (score 6):

I think that is your Windows 10 installation's DVR, which is part of its XBox app.

[image]

The message popping up when starting a game looks like a typical Windows 'ribbon', coming in from either the left or right side of the screen, and has a • symbol to denote your (customizable) 'record' option (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> by default). 

The symbol refers to your 'game bar', where you can start and stop recording:

[image]